two windows use two arrow key
I have an idea, I hope to have two windows side by side on the screen, for example evince on the left and gedit on the right.
I hope that Fn+WASD can move the cursor in evince, and Fn+IJKL can move the cursor in gedit. When I type normally, the input content is displayed in gedit.
How can I do this? Currently I use linux mint 21.3.
Or replace the above Fn+WASD with Win+WASD/LAlt+WASD
